# ID works same as CLASS

Tags: css

I know that ids are for single elements and class is used for multiple elements on the same page. But then why ID styling is applied when there are multiple same ids?

http://jsfiddle.net/WqrAF/

Now, it works then what's the difference?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot select a single id if there are many of it. You will run into problems when you need just one instance of a dom object.

Answer (score 1):

That's because browser try very hard with invalid and malformed markup. They don't always succeed to do what the author intended though.

The solution is to always write valid markup, and check the validation.

Answer (score 1):

This is just the browser coping with invalid HTML. There should never be more than one instance of the `id` attribute with the same value on one page.

Answer (score 0):

The main difference: for `ID`, it should not appear in the same HTML more than once; for `class`, it can be used many times in same HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The behaviour is undefined when you use invalid markup. All major browsers may be able to correct your wrong markup but you cannot rely on that.

Another difference is that ID-Selectors are more *specific* than Class-Selectors:

1. inline style
2. ID
3. classes
4. elements

That means an ID-Selector always wins over any class selector - no matter how many class and element tokens the selector contains. (Unless the class selector styles contain !important. But that's about CSS-Importance and not CSS-Specificity then. This is because CSS-Importance takes place before CSS-Specificity is considered.)